# Using awk, subtract with previous row in all columns and print the result

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need your guidance in one liner command for linux using awk, subtract the row with previous row recursively in all columns and then print the difference values.

I have input as

```
2021-02-15_16 101242 102108 17572 84538
2021-02-15_17 101235 102077 17625 84445
```

Expected output

```
 2021-02-15_17  -7  -31 53  -93
```

I tried this by myself but with no luck.

```
    cat test |awk 'NR==1{s=$3;next}{s-=$3}END{print s}' --> this displays only for 1 column

cat test | awk  'NR==1 {for(i=3; i<=NF; i++){s=$i;next}{s-=$i}{print s}}'
```

Comment: What should the output be if the input file only contains 1 line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR > 1 {for (i=2; i<=5; ++i) $i -= a[i]; print} {split($0,a)}' file

2021-02-15_17 -7 -31 53 -93
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk 'NR > 1 {
   for (i=2; i<=5; ++i)
      $i -= a[i]
   print
}
{
   split($0,a)
}' file
```

Comment: `for (i=2; i<=5; ++i) a[i] = $i` can be replaced with `split($0,a)`

Comment: Thanks that will be even better

Comment: yes @anubhava . it worked. Sorry for delayed repsonse.